# New View not detected in production but works fine in development

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am facing a rather confusing problem here.

In development environment after creating a new view using new model everything works fine. However, when I upload it to the website nothing is displayed. No error is given either.

I tried deleting the cache files manually but to no use. (Deleting cache file works only for the model part).

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

The problem was that the view was not marked as allow(by default all my views are marked as deny).  But why does the user not redirected to the login page when trying to access restricted views?
Any suggestions?

Comment: please tag either 1.3 or 2.x - not both.

Comment: you must also delete the persisent files - or cake will try to use wrong cache files and fail hard. it will work with the right permissions

Comment: Already deleted from persistent files but of no effect...

Comment: you can enable debug in core.php for a sec - and see what it reports.

Comment: @mark debug is set to value 2 but still no errors. It just shows a blank page

Comment: Have you checked your log-files? app/tmp/logs and the apache error log? Are production and development servers using the same PHP version?

Comment: yes they r @thaJeztah

Comment: I think that, without a look at your code it will be hard to solve your problem. Error logs do not show anything? Are you using AuthComponent?

Comment: @thaJeztah Yes i am using AuthComponent.

Comment: Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found. [MissingControllerException] Controller class JsController could not be found... @thaJeztah However I would like to inform you that out of the many views that is working... Only the new Controller & View that I made yesterday is giving the problem even if the new Controller has a single View which prints hello world.

Comment: It seems like the 'css' and 'js' directories are missing in your webroot? At least that is likely the cause of `Controller class CssController could not be found`. However, this should cause problems for all your actions. If you're using the AuthComponent, is the newly created view marked 'Allowed' or are you using ACL? If you're using ACL, is your ACL up-to-date in the online/production database?

Comment: @thaJeztah Yes you are right. The problem was the view was not marked as allowed. However, if its marked as "Deny" then shouldn't it have redirected me to the login page? Every other Deny view does that

Comment: @Bahdeng that's what I would expect as well yeah. However, if something is output before the redirect-header is sent, it may block the actual redirect. I'll post my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You're using the AuthComponent, but have forgotten to mark the new view as 'Allowed', therefore access to the view is blocked if no user is logged-in.

Make the new view 'public' by marking it as 'allowed' in the beforeFilter() of your Controller;

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if (isset($this->Auth)) {
        $this->Auth->allow(array(
            'action1',
            'action2',
            'theActionThatWasAdded',
        ));
    }
}
```

Documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public

Comment: When i don't use Auth->allow for any of the "denied" views it automatically redirects to the login page. Then how is this view different when i haven't done anything that has not been done to all the other views? What puzzles me is that in development it works like a charm but in production site it jes won't work... :(

Comment: I'm not really sure. You mentioned the 'Controller class CssController could not be found' errors the log of your Production-server, possibly something being output before the redirect-header is sent? This seems like a different question though?

Comment: thanks for your kind help... will retry again with someother controller and views and hope it works... ;)

Comment: I copied another working controller n view rename it and tested. It worked fine... lolz

Comment: Possibly some invisible character somewhere blocking the redirects then. Anyway, happy to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache files from app/temp/cache.Check if the folders have sufficient permissions.Check for the hta access file also.